# VB.net Dictionary - getting all values from dictionary equals to 1

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dictionary of exchange rates in VB.net. What I want to get is a dictionary that by typing currency name will return an array of 15 days exchange rates. For example, calling 'USD' in dictionary will return an array of USD/THB rates. My problem all the values in my dictionary are 1.

Here is my code. Although values in my ArrayTemp ( my Array before put in dictionary) are not 1, the values in dictionary are all 1.

```
MarketDataEndRow = .Range("A5").End(XlDirection.xlDown).Row
ReDim ArrayTemp(MarketDataEndRow = 6)
i = oFunction.Match("FX Spot", .Rows(5), 0)
While (.Cells(5,i).Value().ToString = "FX Spot" Or IsNothing(.Cells(5, i).value().ToString)) And Not IsNothing( .Cells(4, i).value().ToString)
    For K = 6 to MarketDataEndRow
        ArrayTemp(K - 6) = .Cells(k, i).value
    Next K
    dictFxSpot.Add(.Cells(4, i).Value, ArrayTemp)
End While
```

Comment: There's not enough information here for us to be able to answer. What is the originating data? We need a sample, as well as a sample of what you expect to see.

Comment: Also: the syntax for your `ReDim` is incorrect. `MarketDataEndRow = 6` returns a `Boolean`, but `ReDim ArrayTemp()` expects one or more numeric values. See the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/w8k3cys2(v=vs.110)).

Comment: Also: when performing logical comparisons, as you are here, proper syntax is to use `OrElse` and `AndAlso`, instead of `Or` and `And`. `Or` and `And` perform bitwise comparisons, and may produce unexpected results. You can find more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/operators-and-expressions/logical-and-bitwise-operators).

Comment: Also, I would recommend not to use the `IsNothing` function which is for compatibility only, it's preferable to use the `Is` (or `IsNot`) comparison operator, i.e. `.Cells(5, i).value().ToString Is Nothing`.  At that, it's unlikely that a call to `ToString` will return a null string, so you may want to use something like `String.IsNullOrEmpty` instead.

Comment: Your problem is likely to be that arrays are a reference type.  Your code as written will put the same array into every entry in the dictionary.  You need to put your array declaration inside the loop so that a new array is created for each dictionary entry.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. @Craig I think the reference type problem is what I'm dealing with. Could you please give me some examples how to solve this ? Thank you

Comment: Oh I got it. Thank you